# Discarding unwanted points in a dataframe

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with 15,000 data points, each with a value of 0, 1, 2, or 3. The data consists of around 25-30 occurrences of the same value, followed 0-2 instances of another value, followed by 25-30 occurrences of yet another value. The longer (25-30 item) sequences follow the pattern 3 -> 1 -> 2 -> 0 always. I need to get rid of the 0-2 instances sandwiched between the two longer sequences. Is there a fast & efficient way to do this? Even better, is there a built in function in python to do this?

Here is an example of how the data looks:
3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1

In this case, I would want to get rid of "0".

One solution I've implemented involves going through every data point and discarding the subsequent value if it does not match what I expect it to. But I need a faster solution because I am collecting the data live.

Comment: You will have to write code, which you do not appear to have even attempted to do.

Comment: You say your data is an array but this looks like a pandas.Series

Comment: Iterating through every point will solve it in O(n), I don't think faster solution [ O(log n ) ] is possible in this case. Since all logn solutions require some form of sorting, but in your case sorting the data will just damage its essence.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you could try:

```
dataList = [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

for x in list:
    if x == 0:
        dataList.remove(x)
print(dataList)
```

Comment: Firstly, Don't use list as a variable name, it's a built-in word and is bad practise.
Secondly, Using a for-loop is a bad idea for deletion of data inside a list as you can get IndexError if the number of times the for loop runs gets shorter. 
Thirdly, You didn't even use nRepeat variable.

Comment: @outcast_dreamer Thank you for the advice, I'm still very new to python.

Comment: don't mention it :D
Keep at it, you will eventually get better